# ssrs expression sum doesn't sum all column

Tags: reporting-services, sum, ssrs-expression

I have a column like:

```
LEFT_PIN_HEIGHT_MIN

 0
 0
 0
 1
 1
 0
```

I wrote it to `Tablix` as below,

`=Sum(Fields!LEFT_PIN_HEIGHT_MIN.Value)`

I want to sum the fields and result must be **"2"** but it doesn't sum the column

and writes all the rows to `Tablix.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the previous answer that your first choice ought to be to calculate this in the SQL, but sometimes that is not as practical.

Are you trying to display the column's sum in each row?  If so, add the dataset name as a second parameter in the sum function, as in

```
=Sum(Fields!LEFT_PIN_HEIGHT_MIN.Value,"Dataset1")
```

Replace `"Dataset1"` with the name of your dataset.  The `Sum` function you're currently using is defining the sum within the context of each row in your tablix.  Adding the second parameter changes that context to return the sum for the entire dataset in each row.

If your tablix is large, this may result in a performance hit, since the expression will evaluate each time it is displayed, hence the preference toward doing it in your dataset query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do It with SQL. Use query to `SELECT SUM(LEFT_PIN_HEIGHT_MIN)`...

If you want to achieve It by SSRS expression you can do It in following:

`Right Click` on `table1_Details_Group` > `Group Properties...`

In `Group on:` field provide `LEFT_PIN_HEIGHT_MIN` click `OK`

To hide `0` > `Right Click` on left side of values row > `Row Visibility` check `Show or hide based on an expression` then write following expression: `=IIF(Fields!LEFT_PIN_HEIGHT_MIN.Value = 0, true, false)` click `OK`

It should work.

Comment: =IIF(...,True,False) is redundant.  That last expression ought to read: =Fields!LEFT_PIN_HEIGHT_MIN.Value = 0